# Python: I need print to return only unique sentence

Tags: python, string, shell

I am trying to take a txt file that has 10 sentences (all words) and pass it as a command line argument to python script. I want to print the sentences that contain the words listed in `dic`. The script below finds the matching sentences but it print the sentences as many times as it finds matching words.

Is there another method that I can use to do this ? Also, I do not want the output to be separated by a line (\n)

```
import sys

dic=["april","aprils","ask","aug","augee","august","bid","bonds","brent","buy","call","callroll","calls","chance","checking","close","collar","condor","cover"]

f=open(sys.argv[1])

for i in range(0,10):
line=f.readline()    
words=line.split()
if len(words) > 3:
    for j in words:
        if j in dic:
            print(line)
```

Output:

```
eighty two is what i am bidding on the brent

eighty two is what i am bidding on the brent

eighty two is what i am bidding on the brent

call on sixty five to sixty seventy

call on sixty five to sixty seventy

call on sixty five to sixty seventy

call on sixty five to sixty seventy

call on sixty five to sixty seventy

no nothing is going on double

i am bidding on the option for eighty five

i am bidding on the option for eighty five

recross sell seller selling sept

recross sell seller selling sept

recross sell seller selling sept

recross sell seller selling sept

recross sell seller selling sept

blah blah blah blah close
```

Required Output:

```
eighty two is what i am bidding on the brent
call on sixty five to sixty seventy
no nothing is going on double
i am bidding on the option for eighty five
recross sell seller selling sept
blah blah blah blah close
```

Comment: put a `break` after `print(line)`, so it does not check other words.

Comment: @trincot , thank you that solved 80% of the problem. Using break completely slipped my mind.

Comment: The other 20% is caused by the newline character in the `line` string. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Suppressing repeated lines in the output

   Add a `break`  after the `print(line)` statement, so the `for` loop on the dictionary words is interrupted
2. Suppressing newlines

   The extra newlines are caused by `f.readline()`, because it will include the `\n` at the end of the returned string. You could remove this with `line.strip()`, but it is probably better to use the `for line in f` syntax instead.

Here is the code:

```
for line in f:    
    words=line.split()
    if len(words) > 3:
        for j in words:
            if j in dic:
                print(line)
                break
```

Comment: To suppress the newlines I did:

`for line in f:    
    words=line.split()
    if len(words) > 3:
        for j in words:
            if j in dic:
                print(line.strip("\n"))
                break`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating one `set` for your dictionary of words and a second `set` containing the words of each line of your file. Then, you can compare the sets using `&`  to get their intersection, or the words common to both. This is more efficient than looping through lists to find like words.

```
import sys

dic=set(["april","aprils","ask","aug","augee","august","bid","bonds","brent","buy","call","callroll","calls","chance","checking","close","collar","condor","cover"])

filename = sys.argv[1]

with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        s = set(line.split())
        if s & dic:
            print(line.strip())
```

Comment: The solution using this method is:

`import sys

dic=set(["april","aprils","ask","aug","augee","august","bid","bonds","brent","buy",
"call","callroll","calls","chance","checking","close","collar","condor","cover"])

filename = sys.argv[1]

with open(filename) as f:
 for line in f:
  if len(line.split()) > 3:
   s = set(line.split())
   if s & dic:
    print(line.strip())`

Comment: Thank you for optimizing the procedure

Comment: what is the `len > 3` check for?

Comment: I want the lines that have more than 3 words only. This is just to handpick Speech to Text output.